# Create COMException from HRESULT

Tags: c#, com

How do one create a COMException given a HRESULT?

I have P/Invoke:ed a win32-method which returns a HRESULT.
If it returns failure I wish to throw a COMException, with the standard error-text.
How should I do that?

1. `throw new COMException(null, hResult)`
2. `COMException e = new COMException;

   e.HResult = hResult;

   throw e;`

Or should I use some other method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`Marshal.GetExceptionForHR()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8t3ykxc.aspx) if you only want to get the exception, or [`Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z72ax64.aspx) if want to throw it too.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the [PreserveSig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.preservesig.aspx) field on your [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) call. This will generate an exception for any non `S_OK`  `HRESULT` returned from the function.

Comment: Would that make functions that return e.g. `S_FALSE` throw? That would be weird, but probably better than not being able to differentiate it from `S_OK`.